# Setting a kotlin lambda from java

Tags: java, kotlin

So say I have some simple data class like this:

```
data class Transaction(
    val time: Long,
    val sender: String,
    val data: ByteArray
)
```

And in Kotlin I have the following method defined:

```
fun handleTransaction(transactionGetter: ()->Transaction) {
    // do something
}
```

How do I go about calling this method from Java?

I've tried trying to make a java lambda but can't figure it out. It is telling me that the parameter is supposed to be a `Function0<Transaction>` but I am not too sure how to define that.

---

Okay so, I figured out I can do this:

```
handleTransaction(new Function0<Transaction>() {
    @Override
    public Transaction invoke() {
        // handle getting transaction           
    }
});
```

Is that really the right way to do it? It is quite ugly.

Comment: Just like any other anonymous interface implementation.

Comment: `() -> createTransaction()` just like a Java Supplier<Transaction>.

Comment: @JBNizet ahhh, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting at least JDK 8, you can do this (if function `handleTransaction` is defined in file `Transaction.kt`):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransactionKt.handleTransaction(() -> new Transaction(
                Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), "system", new byte[0]));
    }
```

If you are targeting anything below JDK 8, then there is no other way other than what you already found.